# How to store data from http service in angular factory

Tags: angularjs

I would like to store the value from /api/login.json globally using a service, but I think I have some sort of timing issue. The console.log statement in the controller tells me that the scope.login object is undefined.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Factory service:

```
myApp.factory('LoginFactory', ['$http', function($http){

    this.data;
    $http.get('/api/login.json').success(function(data) {
        this.data = data;
    });

    return {
        getData : function(){
        return this.data;
    }
  }
}]);
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('AccountsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Accounts', 'LoginFactory', function($scope, Accounts, LoginFactory){
  $scope.login = LoginFactory.getData();
  console.log('$scope.login: %o', $scope.login);    
  $scope.accounts = Accounts.index();

}]);
```

Comment: the issue is that the context of the this keyword is different inside the get from outside of the get...why no just var the data variable

Comment: I tried var'ing the data-variable (var data = {};), but it did not have any influence, other than now I'm just getting the empty object.

Comment: well of course its not as simple as var'ing it you have to remove the this keyword everywhere else and changing the name of the local variable of the success function

Comment: Yes, I took that for implied :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should probably avoid use of the `this` keyword in this context. better just to declare a new variable.

```
myApp.factory('LoginFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var data;
    $http.get('/api/login.json').success(function (d) {
        data = d;
    });
    return {
        getData: function () {
            return data;
        }
    };
}]);
```

you will still have a race issue though, so i would also recommend either promise chaining

```
myApp.factory('LoginFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var promise = $http.get('/api/login.json');
    return {
        getData: function (callback) {
            promise.success(callback);
        }
    };
}]);
```

or even a conditional get

```
myApp.factory('LoginFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var data;
    return {
        getData: function (callback) {
            if(data) {
                callback(data);
            } else {
                $http.get('/api/login.json').success(function(d) {
                    callback(data = d);
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

The last two approaches require you to rewrite your controller though

```
myApp.controller('AccountsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Accounts', 'LoginFactory', function($scope, Accounts, LoginFactory){
  LoginFactory.getData(function(data) {
      $scope.login = data;
      console.log('$scope.login: %o', $scope.login);    
      $scope.accounts = Accounts.index(); //this might have to go here idk
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried your suggestion in the second code block, and it worked well. I just had to update the call in the controller: LoginFactory.getData(function(result){
     $scope.login = result;
  });

Comment: If you could add the change in the controller, I will accept and upvote your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Extending @LoganMurphy answer. Using promise and still adding callbacks is not at all desirable. A better way of writing service could be

```
myApp.factory('LoginFactory', ['$http', function ($http, $q) {
    var data;
    return {
        getData: function () {
            if(data) {
                return $q.when(data);
            } else {
                return $http.get('/api/login.json').then(function(response){
                    data = response;
                    return data;
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with the `this` keyword and also you not handling the promise from the http.get correctly

I would write it like this:

```
myApp.factory('LoginFactory', ['$http', function($http){

    return {
        getData : function(){
        return $http.get('/api/login.json');
    }
  }
}]);


myApp.controller('AccountsCtrl', ['$scope', 'Accounts', 'LoginFactory', function($scope, Accounts, LoginFactory){
  $scope.login = LoginFactory.getData().success(function(data){
     console.log(data);
     console.log('$scope.login: %o', $scope.login); 
  });

}]);
```

Comment: i think the OP wants to cache the result of the ajax get request...unfortunately your solution doesnt do that