# angular factory to store parameter

Tags: angularjs

I want to store a parameter in a factory which will be used cross controller.
I would like to retrieve the parameter's value one time from the server side when the app launches and use it from that point on without querying the server each time.

I'm currently using a factory for a function , for example:

```
app.factory("User",function($http, $log){
        return {
            exportHtmlTableToPdf: function(html_table_id, pdf_title) {
                toExport = [];
                $log.log(html_table_id);
                $log.log(html_table_id);
                //need to maintain the orders of the headers in the table as this is important to the user's report
                headers = [];
                firstRow = true;

                $( "#"+ html_table_id + " tbody tr.ng-scope" ).each(function( i) {
                if ($(this).find('.checkBoxAlerts').prop('checked')) {
                    row = {};           
                    if (headers.length) {
                        firstRow = false;
                    };
                    $(this).find( "td[sortable]:not(.ng-hide)" ).each(function( j) {                
                        row[$(this).attr('data-title')] =  $(this).text();
                        if (firstRow) {
                            headers.push($(this).attr('data-title'));
                        }
                    });
                    toExport.push(row);
                }
                });                     

            }

        };
    });
```

I'm interested in a parameter inside the factory which gets its value one time from the server side using a get/post and is accessible cross controllers, the same as the exportHtmlTableToPdf is.

Thanks

Comment: where is the parameter that you want and the http request? please paste the relevant code

Comment: thanks, already solved it by using this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386092/how-to-store-data-from-http-service-in-angular-factory?rq=1